Игрок видит сквозь объекты из-за шейдера pixelation_shader в Ursina | Python
Использую библиотеку Ursina на питоне для своей игры. В Ursina есть такой шейдер как pixelation_shader, который можно импортировать с помощью данного кода и применить на камеру:
from ursina import *
from ursina.shaders.screenspace_shaders.pixelation_shader import pixelation_shader

app = Ursina()
camera.shader = pixelation_shader # Применение шейдера на камеру

С помощью такого шейдера можно воссоздать эффект старых игр например как Doom. И могу показать как выглядит на данный момент моя игра:
Как вы видите, игра выглядит как старая, что я и хочу сделать. Но вот проблема с этим шейдером. Когда я подхожу к стенам комнаты, то я вижу сквозь этих стен. Но если я уберу шейдер пикселизации, то такой баг пропадает:
